# C++ class with "plug and play" functionality

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a class template called `Machine`:

```
template<std::size_t PARTS>
class Machine
{
    public:
        Machine(const std::array<double, PARTS>& part_values) : part_values(part_values) {}

        int DoSomething(const int input)
        {
            const std::function<std::array<double, PARTS> transformed = this->Transform(input);

            return std::min(4.0, transformed[input]);
        }

    protected:
        const std::array<double, PARTS> part_values = {0};
        const std::function<std::array<double, PARTS>(const int&)> Transform;
}
```

Normally, if I wanted to make this object oriented, I would just have a Machine parent class where I have `Transform` as a member function and override `DoSomething` and `Transform` for each child class. However, the specs are requiring "plug and play"  functionality where the user can easily write up classes by just supplying the `Transform` function without writing up the class definition. An example (located in another file):

```
const int PARTS = 5;
const auto Transform = [](const int& x) 
{
    return std::array<double, PARTS>{x, x*x, x/4, x*5, 9};
};
```

These are supplied to the Machine constructor.

I cannot think of a simpler way to do this, and since there are a lot of these types of classes, it is causing the program to run slower (I think due to std::function) than if I had just done the class inheritance approach.

- What is a good way to determine if `std::function` is the cause of the issue? As using the profiler I only see `DoSomething` being called and not any overhead from `Transform`.
- Also is there a better way to allow the plug and play functionality?

Comment: `std::function` *does* have some overhead, sure. But once you turn on compiler optimizations that overhead is usually pretty tiny and I doubt you would actually notice it in most cases - I would not worry about that but, but if you *do* worry, then create different implementations and *benchmark* them - remember to test optimized builds, *not* debug builds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry added questions at the bottom

Comment: You keep saying "plug and play functionality" and it just reminds me of Windows 95 hardware support. What do you mean? What are these transformations supposed to accomplish? Did you intend to write `transform(input)` instead of `transform[input]`, or do you really have an array of something, and why did you call `this->Transform(input)` - is input really both an argument and an index?

Comment: You can use function pointers instead of `std::function`. The limitation is that the `DoSomething` lambda that you can pass cannot capture anything. Lambdas that do not capture can be converted to function pointers.